# wordpress url with custom post type and taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, url, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a problem with the url, I created a custom post type "collections" and a taxonomy "collection categories", in the taxonomy I included four values: "paintings", "drawing and watercolors", "sculpture", "past sales".

For each value I created a page in the theme folder to wordpress with names such as "taxonomy-collection_categories-paintings.php" and the template name "Paintings Taxonomy" etc.

After creating and associating with each of the four menu items, now when I insert a work and I associate it with a taxonomy value it appears in the taxonomy page with the url mysite.com/collection_categories/paintings, but when I click on single work the url becomes mysite.com/collections/opera-name/, while I would like the url become mysite.com/collection/paintings/opera-name.

In fact the taxonomy should be parent-child of custom post type, url must not appear the title of the taxonomy but the corresponding taxonomy term, sorry for my English, I hope I was clear.

Comment: This is default behavior, because you can assign multiple taxonomys. To achieve your desired behavior, you have to program it, but this is probably more complex.

Comment: There are multiple threads for this , for example http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49141/rewriting-a-custom-post-type-permalink-with-taxonomy-term